# Want to set delay in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set delay in javascript code so that XML file generated before running of javascript . Here is my html code

```
<body onLoad="Func1Delay()">
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
```

In this Func1Delay() function i have written code to delay execution of javascript

```
function Func1Delay()
    {
    setTimeout("load()", 3000);
    }
```

load() is javascript function ? how can i delay execution of javascript code so that xml file successfully generated before code execution??

Comment: How do you load the XML file? I am sure the loading mechanism provides a callback which fires when the file is loaded, after 1, 2, 10 or whatever seconds.

Comment: downloadUrl("location.xml", function(data) {
   var xml = data.responseXML;}) this is how i load xml file in javascript load() function..@Salman A

Comment: `downloadUrl` does provide a callback. This function is retired though.

Comment: then what you suggest me to do @Salman A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your downloadUrl function provides a callback. The callback function fires *automatically, after the XML is loaded*. You do not need a 3 second delay, just move your logic inside the callback function. Something like this:

```
function Func1Delay() {
    downloadUrl("location.xml", function (data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        // do any thing with xml, it is loaded!
        // alert(xml);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the function to execute as soon as possible, but in every case *after* your xml has been successfully generated.

In this case you should prevent using a fixed amount of time (because you don't know the value exactly), but try the following:

```
function load(){

    if (/*check here if the xml has *not yet* been generated*/){
          setTimeout(load,50); // try again in 50 milliseconds
          return;
    }

    // do your stuff here
}
```

This loops as long as your xml is not ready, and kicks in as soon as it's available.

General about setTimeout:

You can pass a string, but this is highly discouraged from for several reasons.
Instead pass a function reference or a function like this:

```
// function reference
setTimeout(load,3000) // no `()` !

// function
setTimeout( function(){load()},3000)
```

If you need paramters be passed to the function, you can't use the first option but need to use the second one, where you can easily pass them `load(params)`.

If you pass a function like this: `setTimeout(load(),3000)` it executes the function `load` and passes its *return value* to the timeout. You however want the function invoked after 3 seconds and thus only pass the reference to the function.

Notice however, that you have a different scope if you execute the functions this way.

Comment: You don't *need* to, what the OP posted does work, provided `load` is defined at global scope. It's best practice (to use a function referenced rather than string), but not *required*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sure, if you want to evaluate a string and also possibly run into scope problems you could do it.

Answer (score 1):

That's how you do it, except you don't want to use a string (although it works — provided you have a function called `load` defined at global scope). `setTimeout` schedules a function to be called a given number of milliseconds later.

It's better to give it an actual function reference:

```
function Func1Delay() {
    setTimeout(load, 3000);

    function load() {
        // Stuff to do three seconds later
    }
}
```

Note that the event you're using to trigger it, the `onload` of `body`, already happens really, really late in the page load cycle, and so whatever you're waiting for may already be done; conversely, if it might take more than three seconds, you might not be waiting long enough. So if there's something you can check to see whether it's done or not, you can poll, like this:

```
function Func1Delay() {

    check();

    function check() {
        if (theWorkIsDone) {
            // Do something with the work
        }
        else {
            // Check back in 100ms (1/10th of a second)
            setTimeout(check, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To add this answer: An inline "callback" function can also be used, but in any case you need to make sure any variables you use are available. In particular, `this` now referes to the scope that called the object, which might be `window` and not the function or object you wrote this `setTimeout()` in.